# How do I set the alignment between the two ends of caption that I normally see?

Tags: captions

I use the following

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
%
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
    %\centering
\caption{(a) The type of circuit described in Ref. [37] that allows the 
recovery of 2n eigenvalues of the averaged noise channel of the
device. The random Pauli gates (blue) are used to twirl the channel and by averaging over a number of random choices of Pauli gates,
the noise channel in the device is transformed into a Pauli channel. In a similar way to randomized benchmarking, by repeating the}
    \label{fig1}
    \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

And get [image]

I want to get caption text aligned at the both end (left and right), like this:  [image]

Comment: Wouldn‘t it be easier to see with a screenshot and relevant code, which compiles?

Comment: you are specifying `justification=raggedright` so explicitly turning off justification and getting a ragged margin. But your example `(Color online) XXXXXXX.` is too short to show the right margin

Comment: unrelated but `\label{fig1:d}` will not work in that position, it must be after `\caption`

Comment: I made a change

Comment: It is useless to post an obscured image of a different document, also as `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` can not be hyphenated Tex will be unable to justify the text, so your test code can't be used . Replace `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` by some text that shows the problem (perhaps `one two three four ` repeated enough times` and make a complete small document that shows the issue and show the image you get from the test file. As it is I can not guess what you are asking about, as I can't see what you get or how you want to change that. Perhaps delete `justification=raggedright`?

Comment: Ok, made a change

Comment: (sub)caption packages don't really work with revtex (they do give warnigs) If you remove them [you get this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K8h0.png)

Comment: Thanks, got it.

Answer (score 1):

As David already told in a comment, package `caption` (and therefore also `subcaption`) and class `revtex4-2` are not really compatible. Usually `caption` warns:

```
Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package),
(caption)                standard defaults will be used.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

because of this.

Nevertheless, to get the wanted result, you can load package `ragged2e` and then use `caption` option `justification=Justified` (note the uppercase `J`!):

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
%
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}% Needed for justification=Justified (uppercase J!)
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false,justification=Justified}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
  %\centering
\caption{(a) The type of circuit described in Ref. [37] that allows the 
recovery of 2n eigenvalues of the averaged noise channel of the
device. The random Pauli gates (blue) are used to twirl the channel and by averaging over a number of random choices of Pauli gates,
the noise channel in the device is transformed into a Pauli channel. In a similar way to randomized benchmarking, by repeating the}
    \label{fig1}
    \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, don't expect, that this will fix all issues with the combination of `caption` and `revtex4-2`.